# Is there relatively simple way to find all exported names from JavaScript text

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, lexical-analysis

So let's say we have some JavaScript es module as text

```js
const ESMText = "export const answer = 42;"
```

I checked ECMAScript [documents](https://tc39.es/ecma262/), and logic for `export` is quite complicated, is there kinda simple way to finde out all exports without executing it or implementing almost full spec lexical analysis stuff (tokenizer, etc...) ?

---

It should be done in browser using JavaScript (maybe wasm)

---

Should be mentioned: obviously parse file using existing parser is the right answer, but whole point of question is to find kinda tricky way to do it

---

it could be easy done with regex, but there is two edge cases that i can't handle:

```js
// destructuring assignment
export const { name1, name2: bar } = o;
export const [ name1, name2 ] = array;

//simultaneous declaration and assignment
export const name1 = 1, name2 = 2/*, … */;
```

*may be someone will figure out something of it*

Comment: well i don't think you should try to implement a full-spec parser, but maybe you can use an existing one?

Comment: @Mulan first: I updated my question (forgot to mention that it should be done in js); second: there is no much option I f I found, maximum was a tokenizer, but only with tokens it will be like implementing half of js grammars or even more, not not sure if this is a good idea

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://pegjs.org/ (parser generator for JavaScript). They also have a JavaScript grammar based on "ECMA-262, 5.1 Edition": https://github.com/pegjs/pegjs/blob/master/examples/javascript.pegjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the end, i did it with `acorn` (inside worker):

```js
self.importScripts("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/acorn/8.8.2/acorn.min.js");
const exp = new RegExp("export", "g");

const ESMText = "export const answer = 42; const innerVar = 'str'"

for (const match of ESMText.matchAll(exp)) {
    const parser = new acorn.Parser({
        ecmaVersion: 2020,
        sourceType: "module"
    }, text, match.index);
    parser.nextToken();
    const statement = parser.parseStatement(true, true, {});
    console.log(statement);
}
```

i checked `acorn` docs and its implementation, after that i find out how to solve my problem with pretty god performance.
in the code abow parsed only export statements

Answer (score 2):

There are many JavaScript parsers: acorn, esprima, Babel, etc. Your best bet is probably to use one of them.

https://astexplorer.net/ lets you experiment with different parsers to see the abstract syntax trees that they generate.

Comment: It's true, but isn't parsing whole file(module) too much for just extracting exported names?

Comment: @vanilla - Maybe. But, given the choice between parsing the entire file using a complete, standards-compliant lexer and parser, and trying to figure out enough of the standard to understand what corners I can cut while still properly extracting exported names, I'd rather start with the guaranteed-to-work approach and refine from there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may use a js parser like `esprima` and extract the exported names.

like the example below:

```js
const esprima = require('esprima');

function getExportedNames(jsCode) {
  const parsedCode = esprima.parseScript(jsCode, { sourceType: 'module' });

  const exportedNames = parsedCode.body.filter(node => node.type === 'ExportNamedDeclaration')
    .map(exportNode => exportNode.specifiers.map(spec => spec.exported.name))
    .reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr), []);

  return exportedNames;
}

const ESMText = "export const answer = 42;export function foo() {}"
const exportedNames = getExportedNames(ESMText);
console.log(exportedNames); // output:  ['answer', 'foo']
```

Update:
referring to the discussion below you may use flatMap(), instead of using reduce() method.

```
const flattened = arr.flatMap(x => x);
```

instead of:

```
const flattened = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr), []);
```

Comment: `.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr), [])` should never be used. Just `.flatMap` instead.

Comment: if you need to aggregate the array elements into a single value, reduce() is the way to go.

Comment: @vanilla did you try this answer? please let me know if it's missing your requirements.

Comment: No, it’s not the way to go. It’s needlessly verbose and needlessly quadratic-time.

Comment: Using .reduce() to concatenate the nested arrays generated by .map() is a common pattern in JavaScript, but using .flatMap() can be more concise and readable. Both implementations will produce the same result, so it's up to user which one he prefers.

Comment: It’s a common *and wholly incorrect* pattern. That one line will become a *bottleneck*, much slower than the parsing step, on just thousands of exports – a performance trap introduced for no reason at all.

Comment: It's worth noting that performance considerations are generally less important for small arrays like the one given in this question. for the .reduce method as the time it takes to complete the operation grows linearly with the size of the array, your point of view matters significantly when large arrays are targeted. Thanks for your discussion, it was informative. I would consider it in future.

Comment: The time the `reduce`+`concat` method takes grows quadratically, not linearly, with the size of the array. `flatMap` would be linear. The example is small, but as it’s just an example we really don’t know what array sizes are under consideration. Like I said, there is just no reason to introduce this performance trap given that `flatMap` is *also* more readable.

Comment: I see your point. But I meant T(n), as the algorithm is linear with respect to the size of the input n.